# Запрос в MYSQL из питона, сравнение UNICODE строк

Tags: mysql, python, utf-8, unicode

Доброе время суток!
Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: из питона пытаюсь обратиться к базе данных и достать нужное значение, сравнивая со строкой, но в результате получаю пустой лист... Использую mysql.connector. Код приведен ниже.

На консоли сервера подобный запрос работает, а из под питона - нет. Вроде бы на сервере все настроено на utf8.

Также, подобный запрос без "WHERE Title like "%s"" выдает все данные и все корректно отображается...

ПЛИЗ ХЭЛП!!!

```
cur = conn.cursor()

townQuery = (u"""SELECT * FROM Towns  WHERE Title like "%s" """)
tqd = (u"%" +u"Серов"+u"%")
cur.execute(townQuery, tqd)

for  i in cur:
    print i
```

Comment: *charset* вы не забыли указать при подключении? http://stackoverflow.com/a/6203782/4827341

Comment: Я mysql.connector не юзал, но кавычки у `like "%s"` точно нужны?

Comment: Alexander, charset указал utf8...

Comment: andreymal, без ковычек совсем не работает...

Comment: Что происходит если tuple передать вместо строки? `cur.execute('SELECT * FROM Towns  WHERE Title like "%s"', (u"%{}%".format(u"Серов"),))` Ещё нужно уточнить правильный ли диалект используется для данного адаптера (посмотреть на hello world пример для `mysql.connector`).

Comment: Ещё проверить, какая кодировка используется при сохранении исходного кода и что она совпадает с `coding:` декларацией на верху модуля.